# show that exists exactly one n such that $\gamma_1$ is homotopic to $\gamma_2 = e^{2\pi int}$

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

Let $\gamma_1 $  be a closed path in $\Bbb{C}\setminus0$ such that $0 \in int (\gamma_1)$

show that exists exactly one $n \in \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$ such that $\gamma_1$ is homotopic to $\gamma_2 : [0,1] \to \{z: |z| = 1\} \quad \gamma_2 = e^{2\pi int}$

Comment: Your question rephrased is just to prove that the first fundamental group of punctures complex plane is Z. And this fact has many proofs. Is this what you needed?

Comment: I dont know what does the first fundamental group of punctures mean

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I meant puctured complex plane. You could just google fundamental group, if it is the definition you asked.